# Bash: convert lower level JSON to escaped string

Tags: bash, jq

I am struggling to use `jq` to massage the input data so that the first level keys are preserved, while the lower level JSON gets converted to escaped strings.

Input JSON:

```
{
  "a": "1",
  "b": {
    "c": "2",
    "d": {
      "e": "3"
    }
  },
  "f": "4"
}
```

Desired output:

```
{
  "a": "1",
  "b": "{ \"c\": \"2\", \"d\": { \"e\": \"3\"} }",
  "f": "4"
}
```

Is there a "pure" `jq` solution to this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`with_entries` and `tostring` seem to do the trick:

```
$ jq 'with_entries(.value |= tostring )' example.json                                               
{
  "a": "1",
  "b": "{\"c\":\"2\",\"d\":{\"e\":\"3\"}}",
  "f": "4"
}
```

Comment: @horia this might be good enough for what you want but you should be careful, as this will convert other types (numbers, booleans) to strings as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jq` with [`map_values`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map(x),map_values(x)) and [`tojson`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Convertto/fromJSON):

```
jq 'map_values(if type == "object" then tojson else . end)' file
```

This is potentially a safer choice than doing `tostring` on all the values, since it won't affect any numbers, booleans, etc.

```
$ cat file
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": {
    "c": "2",
    "d": {
      "e": "3"
    }
  },
  "f": "4",
  "h": [1]
}
$ jq 'with_entries(.value |= tostring )' file
{
  "a": "1",
  "b": "{\"c\":\"2\",\"d\":{\"e\":\"3\"}}",
  "f": "4",
  "h": "[1]"
}
$ jq 'map_values(if type == "object" then tojson else . end)' file
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": "{\"c\":\"2\",\"d\":{\"e\":\"3\"}}",
  "f": "4",
  "h": [
    1
  ]
}
```

Of course, you can JSON-encode arrays or other types by adding to the `if` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`jq "{a: .a, b: .b | tostring, f: .f}" input.json`

Output:

```
{
  "a": "1",
  "b": "{\"c\":\"2\",\"d\":{\"e\":\"3\"}}",
  "f": "4"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, however I prefer something generic, not specific to my input JSON keys.